# Amazon echo change beep sound

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-voice-service, amazon-echo

I just finished installing amazon echo on my raspberry pi.
Im thinking how could I change the beep sound (feedback sound) after you say "alexa" to something else. Like an audio file which says Im listening.
Anyone ever tried or thought about this?
Maybe I could change it before install somewhere but I found nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's difficult.  Look in:

```
samples/javaclient/src/main/resources/res/
```

and tweak the files `alarm.mp3`, `error.mp3`, `start.mp3` and `stop.mp3` to taste.